# Voluntarily treat scholarships as taxable income to get AOTC?

Tags: united-states, taxes, college, education, scholarship

Our AGI is less than $160K and we therefore qualify for the AOTC for our child's college education.

However, due to scholarships our child receives and that are paid directly to the school, qualified education expenses paid out of pocket (i.e. not funded by a 529 disbursement) are likely only about $600 for the fall semester (we don't have the 1098-T yet, obviously), significantly limiting the AOTC we can take ($2000/2500 for $2000/$4000 in QE). However, she does have significant expenses for room and board, computer etc.

Is it possible to treat a scholarship paid directly to the school as taxable income (e.g. by applying it to the non-qualified room and board expenses) on my child's tax return in order to increase qualified education expenses (the net of tuition/books and scholarships) and to take maximum advantage of the AOTC?

Looking at the child tax return (pay a bit more taxes) and parent tax return (pay significantly less taxes) as a whole, this strategy could yield net tax savings.

What else do I need to consider?

(I realize that applying the AOTC in a different year is also an option, but that's not what I'm after.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s assume your child gets the following 1098-T:

•   Box 1: Tuition and required books, i.e. qualified education expenses: $6000
•   Box 5: Scholarships, paid directly to the school: $5400
•   Let’s assume that these are the all the tuition and book expenses your child has and all the scholarships your child received.

Additional assumptions:

•   Your child had $7000 in expenses for room and board. These expenses are NOT included on the 1098-T.
•   Your child had $2000 in other education-related expenses (e.g., computer, supplies, etc.). These expenses are also NOT included on the 1098-T.
•   Your AGI is less than $160000 (married filing jointly) and you want to claim the AOTC. How to go about it?

The first thing to note is that the 1098-T/the issuing school does not make any assumptions about how the scholarships were used nor does it make assumptions about how the scholarships are treated for tax purposes. They don’t care and simply show the various $$$ buckets. It is YOUR/YOUR child’s responsibility on your/your child’s tax returns to come up with the legally correct and optimal tax treatment.

2nd thing to note is that you can claim only expenses for the AOTC that are in Box 1, NET of any scholarships that have been used EXPRESSLY for these expenses, i.e. net of any scholarships restricted to paying for tuition/books. Whether scholarships are restricted or unrestricted in their use is important. In my limited experience, most are unrestricted, but find out from the grantor of these scholarships what the terms are.

Lastly, scholarships used to pay for anything else but Box 1-type expenses, e.g. room and board, equipment or supplies (e.g. laptop) are taxable.

Scenario 1:
•   Let’s assume. The $5400 in scholarships are completely RESTRICTED and are to be used only for tuition/books.
•   This means you cannot use the scholarships for anything but Box 1 expenses ($6000)
•   Using the scholarship for Box 1 expenses makes the $5400 in scholarships tax-free.
•   However, this leaves only $600 to claim the AOTC against ($6000 - $5400).
•   Thus, you would receive a tax credit of $600.
•   Net net, since your child’s taxes are likely lower than what you get for AOTC, you are likely better off, when you look at both tax returns in aggregate (taxes paid by your child vs tax credit received by you). Whether you are indeed better off will depend on your specific tax situation.

Scenario 2:
•   Scholarships are completely UNRESTRICTED.
•   This means you can use the scholarships against the total of $7000 room & board and $2000 for other education-related expenses. This makes the scholarship taxable income and your child pays appropriate taxes on them (kiddie tax).
•   But at the same time, you want to claim a maximum of $4000 for AOTC to receive a tax credit of $2500.
•   The math then is:
o   Apply $2000 of the scholarships against Box 1 expenses. These $2000 are tax-free and this leaves $4000 to claim the AOTC against ($6000 - $2000)
o   Then apply the remainder, $3400, of the scholarships against room/board and other education-related expenses ($7000 + $2000) o your child’s tax return. These $3400 are taxable and your child pays the appropriate taxes (kiddie tax after deductions)
o   Net net, since your child’s taxes are likely lower than what you get for AOTC, you are likely better off, when you look at both tax returns in aggregate. Whether you are indeed better off will depend on your specific tax situation.

I’ve modeled these scenarios in Turbotax for my child’s tax return. TT is set up nicely to handle this approach, since they ask you how much of the scholarships is to be treated as taxable income.

See also: https://www.thetaxadviser.com/issues/2018/may/counterintuitive-tax-planning-increasing-taxable-scholarship-income-reduce-taxes.html (note that kiddie tax aspects have changed a bit since then, but the basic approach still holds). Basically just as described above

Contrary to what was stated in the comments by littleadv, completely legitimate. No fraud, lying or cheating.

Note that there is also an interplay here with 529 disbursements. I’m not getting into this here.

Comment: Turbo tax will let you do whatever you want, it doesn't make it correct or legal.

Comment: True. If you show me exactly, with references, what is not legal here or in the document referenced in the link, I’ll gladly retract the answer.

Comment: I did that in the comments to my answer, including the specific statute that explains that providing false information in order to decrease your taxes is criminal felony fraud. You disagree with my interpretation, and that's your right. It's your risk to take.

Comment: What exact information is wrong?

Comment: Again - you're claiming that you used the scholarship for something other than tuition when the reality is different. You're claiming that the law allows doing what you are proposing, but you haven't quoted any reference to such law. Only an article that says that in some paper the IRS may have said that. That is **not** a legal authority. The fraud statute I quoted is.

Comment: Telling me that I should not lie to the IRS is a complete non-answer. Believe it or not, I already knew that. In the meantime, I talked to both the grantor off the scholarship and the school. The grantor said that the scholarship can be used for tuition or room and board. The school said that they apply the scholarship to the total balance, which is comprised of tuition and room and board., not a specific line item.They don’t differentiate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138919/discussion-between-tmwn6919-and-littleadv).

Comment: I quoted an IRS publication above, that states that scholarships are tax free when they are used for tuition and books. Thus the reverse is also true, namely that a scholarship is taxable when it is not used for tuition and books.

Show me the specific IRS statute that says that I cannot allocate unrestricted scholarships to room and board or other education related expenses.

show me the IRS statute that says that I have to allocate a scholarship to tuition and books or that requires the schools to allocate scholarships to tuition and books 1st.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with what you quoted. All I'm saying is that in your case you *have* used the scholarship for tuition. The IRC Sec. 117 explicitly says that in this case the scholarship is *not* taxable. You're arguing that despite the reality you can report on your tax return something different. I'm arguing that there's no law or regulation allowing you do that.

Comment: why are there then scholarships that can be applied to either tuition or room/board (like the one we got) when they HAVE to be allocated to tuition per IRS statutes? Makes zero sense. If what you are saying is true, scholarships that can be used for room/board should not even exist … since they have to be allocated to/used for tuition anyway. Simply nonsensical.

Comment: If what you are saying is true, then there is no difference between unrestricted  and restricted scholarships. But clearly, both restricted and unrestricted scholarships exist, so I just don’t think you are correct.

Comment: All I’m saying is that the scholarship that is applied to tuition is indeed tax-free, we agree on that. But my point is it does not have to be applied to tuition. If it is unrestricted. You can apply it to room and board and pay taxes on it. Again show me the statute that says that every scholarship has to be applied to tuition. You show me that statute, I concede.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't have to, what I'm saying is that **in your case** it was. And Sec. 117 says that *if* it was *then* it is non-taxable. And Sec. 7201 says that reporting incorrect information to reduce the tax burden is fraud. Based on these two sections I'm claiming that your reporting the tuition as taxable when it is in fact not in order to reduce your tax burden through AOTC would be fraud per Sec. 7201.

Comment: you are just wrong. The school told me They don’t apply the scholarship to a specific line item, the grantor told me it can be applied to room and board. There is simply no set sequence how scholarships have to be applied to education expenses. You have not shown me that there is. So, In the upcoming tax season, that’s what I will do, pay taxes and claim the AOTC. I appreciate you challenging my thinking, but A good answer comprises more than saying that it is a bad idea to lie to the IRS and provide 0 other proof. I’m done here

Comment: I mean, what's the point asking questions if you're going to ignore the answer? Do whatever you want, it's your problem. You asked, I answered. You asked for references - I provided. Don't say I provided 0 proof when I referenced two sections of the Internal Revenue Code.

Comment: from IRS Pub 970, chapter “ Coordination with Pell grants and other scholarships”, I suggest you read this as it exactly describes the situation:

Comment: You may be able to increase your American opportunity credit when the student (you, your spouse, or your dependent) includes certain scholarships or fellowship grants in the student's gross income. Your credit may increase only if the amount of the student's qualified education expenses minus the total amount of scholarships and fellowship grants is less than $4,000. If this situation applies, consider including some or all of the scholarship or fellowship grant in the student's income in order to treat the included amount as paying nonqualified expenses instead of qualified education expenses

Comment: Nonqualified expenses are expenses such as room and board that aren't qualified education expenses such as tuition and related fees.
Scholarships and fellowship grants that the student includes in income don't reduce the student's qualified education expenses available to figure your American opportunity credit.

Comment: Thus, including enough scholarship or fellowship grant in the student's income to report up to $4,000 in qualified education expenses for your American opportunity credit may increase the credit by enough to increase your tax refund or reduce the amount of tax you owe even considering any increased tax liability from the additional income. However, the increase in tax liability as well as the loss of other tax credits may be greater than the additional American opportunity credit and may cause your tax refund to decrease or the amount of tax you owe to increase.

Comment: Your specific circumstances will determine what amount, if any, of scholarship or fellowship grant to include in income to maximize your tax refund or minimize the amount of tax you owe.

The scholarship or fellowship grant must be one that may qualify as a tax-free scholarship under the rules discussed in chapter 1. Also, the scholarship or fellowship grant must be one that may (by its terms) be used for nonqualified expenses.

Comment: Finally, the amount of the scholarship or fellowship grant that is applied to nonqualified expenses can't exceed the amount of the student's actual nonqualified expenses that are paid in the tax year. This amount may differ from the student's living expenses estimated by the student's school in figuring the official cost of attendance under student aid rules.

Comment: The fact that the educational institution applies the scholarship or fellowship grant to qualified education expenses, such as tuition and related fees, doesn't prevent the student from choosing to apply certain scholarships or fellowship grants to the student’s actual nonqualified expenses. By making this choice (that is, by including the part of the scholarship or fellowship grant applied to the student’s nonqualified expenses in income), the student may increase taxable income and may be required to file a tax return.

Comment: But this allows payments made in cash, by check, by credit or debit card, or with borrowed funds such as a student loan to be applied to qualified education expenses.

Comment: Example 1—No scholarship. Bill Pass, age 28 and unmarried, enrolled full-time in 2021 as a first-year student at a local college to earn a degree in law enforcement. This was his first year of postsecondary education. During 2021, he paid $5,600 for his qualified education expenses and $4,400 for his room and board for the fall 2021 semester. He and the college meet all the requirements for the American opportunity credit. Bill's adjusted gross income (AGI) and his MAGI, for purposes of figuring his credit, are $35,050.

Comment: Bill claims the standard deduction of $12,550, resulting in taxable income of $22,500 and an income tax liability before credits of $2,504. Bill claims no credits other than the American opportunity credit. He figures his American opportunity credit based on qualified education expenses of $4,000, which results in a credit of $2,500 and a tax liability after credits of $4 ($2,504 − $2,500).

Comment: Example 2—Scholarship excluded from income. The facts are the same as in Example 1—No scholarship, except that Bill was awarded a $5,600 scholarship. Under the terms of his scholarship, it may be used to pay any educational expenses, including room and board. If Bill excludes the scholarship from income, he will be deemed (for purposes of figuring his education credit) to have applied the scholarship to pay his tuition, required fees, and course materials. His adjusted qualified education expenses would be zero and he wouldn't have an education credit.

Comment: Example 2—Scholarship excluded from income. The facts are the same as in Example 1—No scholarship, except that Bill was awarded a $5,600 scholarship. Under the terms of his scholarship, it may be used to pay any educational expenses, including room and board. If Bill excludes the scholarship from income, he will be deemed (for purposes of figuring his education credit) to have applied the scholarship to pay his tuition, required fees, and course materials. His adjusted qualified education expenses would be zero and he wouldn't have an education credit.

Comment: Therefore, Bill's tax liability after credits would be $2,504.
Example 3—Scholarship partially included in income. The facts are the same as in Example 2—Scholarship excluded from income. If, unlike Example 2, Bill includes $4,000 of the scholarship in income, he will be deemed to have applied that amount to pay for room and board. The remaining $1,600 of the $5,600 scholarship would reduce his qualified education expenses, and his adjusted qualified education expenses would be $4,000.

Comment: Bill's AGI and MAGI would increase to $39,050, his taxable income would increase to $26,500, and his tax liability before credits would increase to $2,984. Based on his adjusted qualified education expenses of $4,000, Bill would be able to claim an American opportunity credit of $2,500 and his tax liability after credits would be $484 ($2,984 − $2,500).

Comment: Example 4—Scholarship applied by the postsecondary school to tuition. The facts are the same as in Example 3—Scholarship partially included in income, except the $5,600 scholarship is paid directly to the local college. The fact that the local college applies the scholarship to Bill's tuition and related fees doesn't prevent Bill from including $4,000 of the scholarship in income. As in Example 3, by doing so, he will be deemed to have applied $4,000 to pay for room and board. Bill would be able to claim the American opportunity credit of $2,500 and tax liability after credits would be $484.

Comment: end quote. just read the friggin examples. this is exactly it, and that’s not me, but the IRS talking. If that’s not enough then, I dont know.

Comment: ex 4 in particular: “Scholarship applied by the postsecondary school to tuition. The facts are the same as in ex 3—Scholarship partially included in income, except the $5,600 scholarship is paid directly to the college. The fact that the college applies the scholarship to Bill's tuition and related fees doesn't prevent Bill from including $4,000 of the scholarship in income. As in Example 3, by doing so, he will be deemed to have applied $4,000 to pay for room and board. Bill would be able to claim the American opportunity credit of $2,500 and his tax liability after credits would be $484.”

Comment: for your convenience: https://www.irs.gov/publications/p970#en_US_2021_publink100060350

Comment: probably still not enough to convince you, but, no offence, I’ll go with what the IRS says. always remember: Sec. 7201 says that reporting incorrect information to reduce the tax burden is fraud.

Comment: lollollollollol

Comment: but maybe the IRS is wrong and you are right???

Comment: Technically, the IRS publications and instructions are not legal authority and the US Tax Court has ruled before contrary to them (based on the IRS suits, mind you). So yes, it may be. But again - you don't need to convince me, you only need to convince yourself (and the IRS agents auditing you) and you seem to be pretty convinced.

Comment: You crack me up … have a great day! :-)

Answer (score 2):

The main point of contention appears to be the following question:

> Is it possible to treat a scholarship paid directly to the school as
> taxable income (e.g. by applying it to the non-qualified room and
> board expenses) on my child's tax return

As you have already found, ["Publication 970 (2021), Tax Benefits for Education"](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p970) is quite clear that **yes**, one can.  This is described explicitly in the following example [*emphasis* mine]:

> Example 4—Scholarship applied by the postsecondary school to tuition.
>
> The facts are the same as in Example 3—Scholarship partially included
> in income, except the $5,600 scholarship is paid directly to the local
> college. The fact that the local college applies the scholarship to
> Bill's tuition and related fees *doesn't prevent Bill from including
> $4,000 of the scholarship in income*.

A similar situation also arises in this example, though it is not directly relevant to your question:

> Example.  In 2021, Ms. Allen makes a payment directly to an eligible
> educational institution for her grandson Todd's qualified education
> expenses. For purposes of claiming an American opportunity credit,
> Todd is treated as receiving the money from his grandmother and, in
> turn, paying his qualified education expenses himself.

Another user contends that this is fraud and a misrepresentation of the actual situation.  They ask for a reference to a law or regulation allowing this, with the qualification that an IRS publication is not legal authority.  While I have personally favorably resolved a dispute with the IRS regarding whether a scholarship was taxable income, I am not a tax lawyer nor accountant [and insert any other necessary qualifiers here].  Nonetheless, I believe this user in incorrect.  Specifically, [26 CFR [IRC] § 1.25A-5(c)(3)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/26/1.25A-5#c_3) states the following [*emphasis* mine]:

> (3) Scholarships and fellowship grants. For purposes of paragraph
> (c)(1)(i) of this section, a scholarship or fellowship grant is
> treated as a qualified scholarship excludable under section 117 except
> to the extent -
>
> (i) The scholarship or fellowship grant (or any portion thereof) *may*
> be applied, by its terms, to expenses other than qualified tuition and
> related expenses within the meaning of section 117(b)(2) (such as room
> and board) *and the student reports the grant (or the appropriate
> portion thereof) as income* on the student's federal income tax return
> if the student is required to file a return; or

The ["paragraph (c)(1)(i) of this section" mentioned here](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/26/1.25A-5#c_1_i) is the bit that would normally exclude a qualified scholarship from income under 117, as mentioned [in the comments](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/152344/voluntarily-treat-scholarships-as-taxable-income-to-get-aotc#comment309601_152347), and also not count for the purposes of determining the amount of an education tax credit.  The revenue code explicitly includes [examples](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/26/1.25A-5#c_4) of the application of these rules, and they involve the choice of categorization of scholarships as income.

In summary, it appears that both the Internal Revenue Code and the publications of the IRS allow for the reporting of a scholarship as income if it *may* be applied to expenses other than tuition, even if it was in fact used for tuition.

See also [26 CFR § 1.25A-5(b)(1)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/26/1.25A-5#b_1) which is relevant to the example above regarding Ms. Allen.  It does not directly address your question, but does demonstrate that even if Ms. Allen paid an institution directly, it is *treated as* a payment through Todd specifically for the purposes of section 25A ("American Opportunity and Lifetime Learning credits").

Comment: Thank you for pitching in here. I think we are in alignment: the approach is perfectly legal, assuming that the IRS will not renege on its own rules. This was, as you have read an arduous, yet valuable discussion: the value lies in your thinking being challenged and you having to think everything through. Now I gotta figure out whether this approach, factoring in all the cash flows (taxes to be paid vs. credits vs. 529 disbursements and a bunch of other factors/flows) makes sense. But that's a question for another day! :-)